# DateTime issue in month given at first

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, .net-3.5

I have hosted my web site application after publishing in UK. It is not correctly validating the following code

```
DateTime dtTemp = DateTime.MinValue;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(txtDate.Text, out dtTemp))
{
    txtDate.Focus();
    throw new Exception("Expiry Date not valid");
}
```

textbox value is `07/23/2012` (mm/dd/yyyy)

Answer (score 1):

If you want all user culture behaviour to be en-GB( I used UK as an example):

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo enGb = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");

System.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = enGb;
System.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = enGb;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DateTime`'s [`TryParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) method. You can specify the format ("MM/dd/yyyy") and the culture:

```
DateTime dtTemp;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", 
    new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dtTemp) 
{
    txtDate.Focus();
    throw new Exception("Expiry Date not valid");
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require Matthew to override all culture influenced validators etc? What if he would want his client-side validation to work?